# any idea to decrease requests via GET

Tags: php, get, request

i made a video.php page that will show the videos from youtube depending on id of the video on youtube,so i made something like that

```
if($_GET['id']=="jquery11"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6PM6t5RFR2w?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }

if($_GET['id']=="jquery12"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fE0GC7KFIno?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }

if($_GET['id']=="jquery13"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xuFa2R4c6Gc?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }

if($_GET['id']=="jquery14"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M971xYWiS7M?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }

if($_GET['id']=="jquery15"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oZ_J422z4WI?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }

if($_GET['id']=="jquery16"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tYJMitUfSvs?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }


if($_GET['id']=="jquery17"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wZPhQzqGzls?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }


if($_GET['id']=="jquery18"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Cdwn2JoCYQ0?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }


if($_GET['id']=="jquery19"){
    ?>
<div id="video" ><iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cKCiNf23Atg?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

    <?
    }

?>
```

any idea to change this method that will decrease get requests?i tried making associative array ,but i think it's same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$map = array(
    "jquery11" => "6PM6t5RFR2w",
    "jquery12" => "fE0GC7KFIno",
    "jquery13" => "xuFa2R4c6Gc",
    "jquery14" => "M971xYWiS7M",
    "jquery15" => "oZ_J422z4WI",
    "jquery16" => "tYJMitUfSvs",
    "jquery17" => "wZPhQzqGzls",
    "jquery18" => "Cdwn2JoCYQ0",
    "jquery19" => "cKCiNf23Atg"                 
);

$id = $_GET['id'];

if( array_key_exists( $id, $map ) ) {
    echo <<<HTML
    <div id="video" >
        <iframe   width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$map[$id]}?autoplay=1&controls=2" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
HTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of your possible ids, and then check if the variable being passed is in the array by using in_array under an if statement, and then just assign the proper url from there.

Comment: thanks mrtchie,but checking var need the the same GET request ,because the visitor will choose to open the video from another page,and i want to know what's the video that he choose to watch,and this will be only via get to get id of video

Answer (score 1):

Untested - should work tho:

```
<?php

$request = $_GET['request'];



$accepted_requests = array(1 =>'jquery1', 2 => 'jqery2', 3 => 'jquery3');

$utube_urls = array(1 => 'url', 2 => 'url', 3 => 'url');


    if(in_array($request, $accepted_requests)){

                foreach($accepted_requests as $k=>$v){

                    if($request === $v){

                            foreach($utube_urls as $keys => $vals){

                                    if($k == $keys){
                                        echo $vals;
                                    }

                            }

                    }


                }


    }
```

?>

UPDATED THE CODE: Missed the 's' on $val - fixed now